# How to call TS method without exporting base class

Tags: javascript, c#, typescript, asp.net-core

How to call method of Typescript class from different typescript class without exporting the base class that is having the method?
Here is a scenario:

```
class ControllerA{
private MethodTobeCalled()
  {
  // Logic
  }
}

export class ControllerB
{
private CallingMethod()
  {
  // I need to call the method MethodTobeCalled() from here for click event 
  // using addEventListner.
 }
}
```

I know MethodTobeCalled method is private but is there any way to call this method without exporting ControllerA class.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution is to make it public with an `_` prefix i.e.

```
class ControllerA{
  _MethodTobeCalled()
  {
  // Logic
  }
}

export class ControllerB{
  // no you can call it
}
```

An `_` prefix was the convention for api consumers that this method is internal (before `private` became a thing).

Comment: what will prefix _ do in my case? I need to call the method using addEventListner

Comment: Added a note about the convention.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a good practice to call one controller's method from another one.
You should take one common service between them and by using that service you can achieve what you want.

```
export class SubjectsService {
    private subject = new Subject<any>();
}
class ControllerA {
    constructor(private subjectSerice: SubjectsService) {
        subjectSerice.subject.subscribe(() => this.MethodTobeCalled());
    }
    private MethodTobeCalled() {
        // Logic
    }
}

export class ControllerB {
    constructor(private subjectSerice: SubjectsService) { }
    private CallingMethod() {
        // I need to call the method MethodTobeCalled() from here for click event 
        // using addEventListner.
        subjectSerice.subject.next();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not able to understand at what class are you pointing using Subject<any>? Can you please explain in detail?

Comment: Subject class available in rxjs. Yon can import that like this. >>> 
import {  Subject } from 'rxjs';

Comment: the above code is of TypeScript in Asp .net core project. How can I do it in Typescript in asp .net core?